# what is ssl and how can i use to make my website secure?

Tags: ssl

Can anyone tell me about SSL and how it can be used to secure a website?

Comment: Your question is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: In particular note that it doesn't make your *website* secure, only the connection *between* your website and the customer. SSL will do nothing to protect you from SQL injection, XSS, XSRF etc.

Comment: Worth noting that SSL has been superceded as a standard by TLS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is an encryption method to send data securely over http. If you've seen a site with https:// at the beginning that means that it is using SSL. To use ssl to secure your own site, you need hosting that supports it (most do), you need to purchase an SSL certificate from a signing authority (Verisign is an example), and you need to write into your web application to switch to ssl when needed.

Comment: Note: You can also get SSL/TLS certificates for free from Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 2):

SSL doesn't secure your website- it merely encrypts the flow of information between the server and the browser. Despite SSL, you would still be vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting, non-authenticated requests etc...